# React JS: How to send an event down the component tree?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

So I have this React JS project and I'm stuck on this problem:
My app look like this (It's more complicated but this is what I'm talking about...):

```
<App>
  <Container>
    <Item />
  </Container>
  <Button />
</App>
```

What I need to do is that when I click the Button a method is called in Item. I was thinking I could do something like send an event from App to Item via props. So it woul look like this:

```
class App extends React.Component{
  ...
  event buttonClicked `\\idk something like this...`
  ...
  render(
    <div>
      <Container event={buttonClicked} />
      <Button onClick={buttonClicked} />
    </div>
  )
  ...
}

class Container extends React.Component{
  ...
  render(
    <Item event={this.props.event}/>
  )
  ...
}

class Item extends React.Component{

  _buttonClicked(){
  ... `\\This happens when I click the button.`
  } 
  ...
}
```

Is something like this possible?
Thanks :)

Comment: You can use the react context API. 
https ://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to pass down bound event handlers into the child components, and bubble up the events. What you have described is essentially correct

What you can do here is:

- Define `buttonClickHandler` in `App`
- Pass in the `buttonClickHandler` into `Button`
- Pass in the result or operation of `buttonClickHandler` into your item container via. Props
- Invoke this result in your item component

There are multiple other ways to do this:

[Multiple patterns](https://www.ctheu.com/2015/02/12/how-to-communicate-between-react-components/#my-components-are-not-directly-related) exist to do that:

- Event Emitter/Target/Dispatcher : the listeners need a reference to
  the source to subscribe.
- Signals: similar but you don’t use any random strings here. Each
  signal is a specific object. You know exactly what events an object
  can handle.
- Publish/Subscribe: you don’t need a specific reference to the source
  that triggers the event, there is a global object accessible
  everywhere to handle all the events. It’s like being anonymous. You
  have the notion of topic (a string) where you can store and retrieve
  the events data.